# htaccess redirect to dynamic subpages

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to use a redirect to the same page but with a query string.

```
RewriteRule ^fixtures(.*)$ views/fixtures.php 
RewriteRule ^fixtures/(.*).([a-zA-Z_-]*) views/fixtures.php?date=$1
```

When I click any links from the page, nothing happens. In chrome debugger it cancels the request.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser and what is your target URL?

Comment: If i paste the url directly in it works fine.  url something like /fixtures/my-sub-page  But if i click a link from the /fixtures/ page nothing happens

Comment: The above code doesn't actually work when I paste the URL, but if I change the first line to this

    RewriteRule ^fixtures/?$ views/fixtures.php

Then it does work if I paste the URL, but still not when clicking a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great to see a working example but just looking at your rewrite rules it seems there might be a small issue with your regex.

The issue I can see is that your first line expects something like:

`example.com/fixtures*absolutelyanythingeleseontheurl*`

But I think this is being overidden by the next line which is capturing two sections of the url, anything after `fixtures/` and anything after the fullpoint that is `a-zA-Z`, `_` or `-`. But your initial `.*` has already taken care of that.

`RewriteRule ^fixtures/(.*).([a-zA-Z_-]*) views/fixtures.php?date=$1`

Have you tried something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^fixtures$ views/fixtures.php 
RewriteRule ^fixtures/(.*) views/fixtures.php?date=$1
```

The above would do the following:
`example.com/fixtures/` will resolve to `views/fixtures.php`
and the next line would resolve to the following:

e.g. `example.com/fixtures/22-06-2014` to `views/fixtures.php?date=22-06-2014`

Comment: This also works when pasting the url.  but if I click a link to the url from /fixtures/ then the GET request gets cancelled.  Could it be to do with the request essentially coming from the same referrer?

Comment: what does the second link look like exactly, you don't need to give me a domain if you prefer not to.

Comment: *“Also your pattern `[a-zA-Z_-]` will not work as expected as the hyphen must be at the front `[-_a-zA-Z]`”* – first _or_ last in character class are valid positions for a hyphen to be meant literally; only somewhere in-between it would have to be escaped to not specify a character range.

Comment: You are right, I am not sure which corner of my brain I grabbed that from, edited the answer to be more accurate. It was half right!